# Inserting HTML DOM elements loaded from an XML file w/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom, google-maps

If there's an easier/better way to do this, please say so (I'm just starting to learn JS, first language), but here's what I am trying to accomplish:

I have an XML file containing a set of markers for google maps, ie:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<markers>
  <marker name="Our Venue" lat="32.735873" lng="-117.255323" icon="wedding">
    &lt;div id="info"&gt; &lt;h2&gt;Title&lt;/h2&gt; &lt;a href="http://site.com/link.html"&gt;Official web site&lt;/a&gt; &lt;p&gt;Blah blah blah!&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
  </marker>
...
```

I can get jQuery to load all the info and parse it into google.maps.Marker(s):

```
    jQuery.get("map_data.xml", {}, function(data) {
        jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
            var marker = jQuery(this);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(marker.attr("lat")), parseFloat(marker.attr("lng")));
            var title = marker.attr("name");
            var icon = marker.attr("icon");
            var markerContent = marker.contents();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: crIconRegistry[icon],
                title: title
            });
```

Now, I'd like when I click on the map marker for it to insert the HTML content from the XML file into a DIV on the page, something like this:

```
jQuery.jcps.insertFromMap = function (speed, target, markerContent) {
    if (speed == 0) {
    $(target).html(markerContent);
}
else {  
    $(target).fadeToggle(speed, function(){$(this).html(markerContent);}).fadeToggle(speed);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    jQuery.jcps.insertFromMap(crFaderSpeed, crDefaultPanel, markerContent);
});
```

However, when I try this (in safari, haven't tested others yet) I get the following error: "WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: DOM Exception 4: A Node was used in a different document than the one that created it"

TIA for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, although I'm not sure why this made a difference.  My previous code used the variable name "marker" twice: first to hold the XML jQuery object, then re-defined to hold the google.maps.Marker object.  There must have been a conflict I was unaware of, because changing the variable name solved the issue.  Revised code:

```
jQuery.get("map_data.xml", {}, function(data) {
        jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
            var node = jQuery(this);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(node.attr("lat")), parseFloat(node.attr("lng")));
            var title = node.attr("name");
            var icon = node.attr("icon");
            var markerContent = node.contents().text();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: crIconRegistry[icon],
                title: title
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                jQuery.jcps.insertFromMap(crFaderSpeed, crDefaultPanel, markerContent);
            });
        });
    });
```

Thanks though for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you use markerContent more than once? It may lead to wonderous things: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KMYbG/). A way around that is to use [.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/): [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KMYbG/1/)

Comment: Nope, I'm only using it once, same as in my example code.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

For full details, please see the excellent explanation at [Cross-Browser Scripting with importNode()](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crossbrowserscripting)

You have to check if `importNode` is supported before adding `markerContent` in `target`.

If you are using jQuery 1.5 then see [parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), which seems to have taken care of this issue (though I haven't tested it myself).

Comment: Ah, that article sounds like my same problem.  The docs for parseXML aren't very clear, I'll have to try it out in the morning and see what I get :)

Comment: parseXML() doesn't seem to solve the problem, although I guess I may be doing it wrong.  I also tried converting the jQuery object into a simple string and inserting that, but I get the same error.  Very confused.

Comment: Did you try changing this line: var markerContent = marker.contents(); to var markerContent = marker.html(); ?

Answer (score 0):

your original code failed because you tried to merge dom nodes from one document into another - safari balks on that (firefox 7, chrome 15 don't though they probably should). as ritesh pointed out, you can call the dom function `importNode`.

however, to avoid a deep copy of the dom node to be imported, use `adoptNode`.

it is supported by all major browsers including ie 9 (personally tested on safari 5, chrome 15, firefox 7).

hopefully this is helpful additional info,

best regards, carsten